# is it necessary to wait for termination of all the threads before request gets complete in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a web api project in which user perform some action and all the related user get notification regarding the user activity. To notify every user i am starting a new thread which perform the desire action. is it necessary to wait for this thread to terminate before request gets complete and return result to user.

P.S. Execution time for thread may increase with no of user.

Please Suggest any alternate if possible

Program Logic(Presently i am using await function to wait for async function to execute)

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> doSomething(arguments)
{  
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <!-- Perform some operation which includes some database transcations--!>

    if(operation succesed)
    {
        await Notification(userid);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code - how do you start thread, how do you notify user and how do you wait for thread termination

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i updated question with program logic. Please let me know if that is clear to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is going to be a long running function and there is no direct impact on the current function then there is no need to wait. Fire and forget. You can safely remove the await.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> doSomething(arguments) {  
    //... Perform some operation which includes some async database transactions

    if(operation succesed) {
        NotificationsAsync(userid); //Start notifications and continue
    }

    return result;
}
```

I would suggest using a messaging queue for jobs like that but that is a more advanced topic which is out of scope for this question.

Comment: After removing await it gives  me warning that thread is not complete 

P.S. Notification Function uses dbcontext defines in the controller so should i needed to create local instance of dbcontext for the function

Comment: Yes the compiler will show the warning but it works.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Nkosi for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var userIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Console.WriteLine("Updating db for users...");

    // Start new thread for notficiation send-out
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var i in userIds)
            Console.WriteLine("Sending notification for #user " + i);

    }).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Notifcation all sent!"));

    Console.WriteLine("Return the result before notification all sent out!");
}
```

If you remove `await` in front of Task.Run() (equivalent to Notifcation() which returns Task<> in your case) and run then it will create separate thread for notification send-out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> doSomething(arguments)
    {  
     bool isInsertDone ,isUpdateDone = false;

     //create thread list
      var task = new List<Task>();

      // parallel tasks to thread list and execute that tasks 
       task.Add(Task.Run(() =>
          {`enter code here`
              isInsertDone = insertData(arguments)
           }));
           task.Add(Task.Run(() =>
           {
              isUpdateDone  updateData(arguments)
           }));

        // wait for execute all above tasks
         Task.WaitAll(task.ToArray());

        // return response by result of insert and update.
        return Ok<bool>(isInsertDone && isUpdateDone);
    }
```